# Issues in printing image in itextpdf

Tags: android

I'm making an application where on button click i'm  printing everything on pdf and for that purpose i'm using itextpdf as far as string is concerned it gets printed but i'm not able to print an image i did some research but didn't get a proper solution for my problem apart from image everything is working fine
here is my code for making pdf

```
private Image addImageToPdf(Uri uri) {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return image;
    }

}

     public void addTitlePage(Document document) throws DocumentException
        {
            // Font Style for Document
            Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
            Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 22, Font.BOLD| Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.GRAY);
            Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
            Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);

            // Start New Paragraph
            Paragraph prHead = new Paragraph();
            // Set Font in this Paragraph
            prHead.setFont(titleFont);
            // Add item into Paragraph
            prHead.add("Infomedia\n");
            //prHead.add("\n");
            prHead.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            Paragraph cat = new Paragraph();
            cat.setFont(catFont);
            cat.add("\n");
            cat.add("Report\n");
            cat.add("\n");
            cat.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

            // Add all above details into Document
            document.add(prHead);
            document.add(cat);
            document.add(table);

            /* Header values*/
            table = new PdfPTable(2);
            cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Category"));
            cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Values"));
            cell1.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell2.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

            cell1.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell1.setPadding(5);

            cell2.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell2.setPadding(5);

            cell1.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
            cell2.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);

            /*Table values*/
            cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("From"));
            cell3.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell3.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell3.setPadding(5);

            cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(arrival));
            cell4.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell4.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell4.setPadding(5);

            cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("To"));
            cell5.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell5.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell5.setPadding(5);

            cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(destination));
            cell6.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell6.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell6.setPadding(5);

            cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Travel Purpose"));
            cell7.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell7.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell7.setPadding(5);

            cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(travel_type));
            cell8.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell8.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell8.setPadding(5);

            cell9 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Work Description"));
            cell9.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell9.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell9.setPadding(5);

            cell10 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(workdescription));
            cell10.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell10.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell10.setPadding(5);

            cell11 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Expense Given"));
            cell11.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell11.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell11.setPadding(5);

            cell12 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(expense_amount));
            cell12.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            cell12.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
            cell12.setPadding(5);

              cell13 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Pass"));
        cell13.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell13.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell13.setPadding(5);

        cell14 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(addImageToPdf(imageView)));
        cell14.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        cell14.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        cell14.setPadding(5);
             table.addCell(cell1);
            table.addCell(cell2);
            table.addCell(cell3);
            table.addCell(cell4);
            table.addCell(cell5);
            table.addCell(cell6);
            table.addCell(cell7);
            table.addCell(cell8);
            table.addCell(cell9);
            table.addCell(cell10);
            table.addCell(cell11);
            table.addCell(cell12);

            // add table into document
            document.add(table);

            // Create new Page in PDF
            document.newPage();
            //Toast.makeText(this, "PDF File is Created.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

      Here is my code getting image to imageview






protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                    return;
                }
                if (requestCode == GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri path = data.getData();
                        try {
                            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), path);

                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(Work.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                } 
      I'm also converting it to string for uploading it to database i don't know if it is useful for saving it in pdf




private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
            }
```

Comment: You are not adding cell 13 and 14
table.addCell(cell13);
table.addCell(cell14);

Comment: I was adding cell 13 and cell 14 but i dont know what to pass in new phrase

Answer (score 0):

First of all retrieve image from uri using the code given below

```
private Image addImageToPdf(Uri uri) {
    Image image = null;
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), uri);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return image;
    }

}
```

Now pass this image further for adding into PDF Cell

```
public PdfPCell createCellWithImage(Image content, int colspan, int rowspan, int border, int alignment) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", font));
    cell.setPadding(10);
    cell.addElement(content);
    cell.setColspan(colspan);
    cell.setRowspan(rowspan);
    cell.setBorder(border);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Manish Negi but how can i add image to my existing table without using create CellWithImage i have updated my code as per ypur answer please see

Comment: When i'm adding this line cell14 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(addImageToPdf(imageView)));  it is showing error addImageToPdf
(android.net.Uri)
in Work cannot be applied
to
(android.widget.ImageView)

Comment: you should be calling createcellwith image from table.addCell()

Comment: what should i pass for createCellWithImage because when i pass imageview it is showing error

Comment: what error?  you are supposed to send image not imageview .. if you have uri of image you can get image using the first piece of code

Comment: when i'm adding this  table.addCell(createCellWithImage(imageView));

Comment: It is showing error createCellWithImage() in Work cannot be applied to:
Expected Parameters:
Actual Arguments:
 
content:
com.itextpdf.text.Image
imageView  (android.widget.ImageView)
colspan:
int

rowspan:
int

border:
int

alignment:
int

Comment: What should i add in  cell14 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(//Here)); that is what i'm not able to understand

Comment: do you have uri of image?

Comment: No i dont know how to create uri of image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168376/discussion-between-manishnegi-and-smith).